# How to get Picasa images from Picasa using RSS Feed

Tags: php, xml, rss, picasa

I use this code for get all images from my account picasa but without result :

```
$content = file_get_contents("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/107745136468823194427?alt=rss&kind=photo&hl=fr&imgmax=1600");
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
foreach($x->channel->item as $entry => $value){

    $title  = $value->title;
    $image  = $value->enclosure->attributes()->url;
    $urlimg = $image[0];
    echo '<img src="'.$urlimg.'>"';
}
```

What the problem ? Thanks

Comment: Note that you need cookies to access all photos including non-public (since you are not set param `access=public`).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this code please?

```
<?php 
$content = file_get_contents("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/107745136468823194427?alt=rss&kind=photo&hl=fr&imgmax=1600");
$x = simplexml_load_string($content);
foreach($x->channel->item as $entry => $value){

    $title  = $value->title;
    $image  = $value->enclosure->attributes()->url;
    $urlimg = $image[0];
    echo '<img src="'.$urlimg.'>"';
}
```

Comment: I have four images but i get one image !!

Comment: Sorry but why you not use [api](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php)?.. I'm reading examples for pick images from feed, but with api is very easy.. Try to read this [article](http://ref.miru.co.nz/tools/photos/picasa/integratingpicasa/picasarss), i seed that is necessary your apitoken

Comment: A good url for read your images from **test** album is [here](https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/107745136468823194427/albumid/5991781597970591713?alt=rss&kind=photo&hl=it) you can change album from albumid/5991781597970591713 param.. From this link a see your 3 images